# Using transformation including a permutation matrix to fit a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model

reference: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~bates/UseR2008/WorkshopD.pdf from page 97.

I want to fit a linear mixed model. $Y|B=b\sim N(X\beta+Zb,\sigma^2 I)$ and $B\sim N(0,\Sigma(\theta))$. Here I choose not to use $\sigma^2$ in $B$. $B$ is q-dimensional vector.

According to the slides, $B=TSP'u$ where $\Sigma(\theta)=TSS'T'$ and $u\sim N(0, I_q)$, $P$ is called permutation matrix. But what is $P$? I think $B=TSu$ is the correct form without $P$.

EDIT:

To be specific, in the example on page 50 of http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~bates/UseR2008/WorkshopD.pdf, the permutation P has two purposes: reduce fill-in and “post-order” the columns to keep nonzeros near the diagonal. The slides do not illustrate how P is generated. I do not know what "fill-in" mean, either.

Comment: Your formulas have no $P$ ...

Comment: Exactly. The slides do not include the definition of $P$, so I am confused about it.

Comment: You need to read the slides.  See page 50.